# How to Route Request in IIS 7

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis, web-config

I am using IIS 7 and PHP as the backend programing language but I am not so friendly with web.config file i want to route the request to a php file 
Example:
If a user open http://example.com/2/ then i need web.config to route this as a request to my php script ie, http://example.com/page.php?id=2

I can do this with .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(page\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

but i need the same with web.config
Can anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have finally hit an solution for URL rewrite in IIS 
that is a module of IIS known as URLREWRITE and can be downloaded from : 
[IIS URL REWRITE](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
after installation you can create a blank rule under that and route the request to any particular file
for example:
http://example.com/post/100002389
will be routed to :
http://www.example.com/post.php?post_id=100002389